# Office 365 exchange connection refused proxy server

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server

Basically my application trying to connect office 365 exchange via proxy server, connection getting error target server actively refuse it (dynamic 
 IP)XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443.

Any idea to connect exchange or How to bypass the proxy?

Comment: can you add more infos here please? With these information its not clear what you wish to build/perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for it.

[Link to add proxy setting in config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings)